# Does an algorithm exist that transforms any connected graph, cyclic or not, into tree form?

Tags: graphs, trees

I developed an algorithm that transforms any simple connected graph, cyclic or not, into a tree.
The resulting tree is syntax-preserving, in a sense that it allows to reconstruct the original input graph and only the original input graph. In other words, the constructed tree preserves adjacency information, while resolving cycles.
Moreover, I assume that with the constructed tree allowing to reconstruct only the original input graph, no other graph that is structurally different can exist that would result in an identical tree form.

I did some research on algorithms that transform graphs into tree form, but I was unable to find another algorithm that would work for any simple connected graph like described above.
However, I am pretty such there must exist something.

So maybe one more experienced in graph theory can help me out.
It would be highly appreciated.

Alex

Comment: Here is another algorithm. Choose your favorite binary encoding, and encode the graph as a binary string. Now encode the binary string as a tree, for example by taking a path, hanging from every vertex an optional edge (to signify 1 rather than 0), and adding some gadget to mark the root (say 10 paths of length 2). With a little bit of work, this encoding would be reversible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I do not fully understand your approach? How would you encode a cyclic graph in binary form? Could you also elaborate more on how that path construction would work?

Comment: @user121863, In any way you want, really. If you have a graph then you must represent it somehow in your memory. That is, you are already encoding it with some binary string.

Comment: What do you call a *simple* connected graph ?

Comment: If your question is "is my algorithm unique ?", then 1) it is probably not, 2) without you explaining it we cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

In a general graph, the number of edges can go up to $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ (where n is the number of verticies). But in a tree, that number is always $n-1$.

Then, we understand that its impossible to convert a graph to a tree preserving syntax without increasing the memory for each node by a linear factor, or increasing the number of nodes significantly.

Let us define a unique number for every node (in any way you like).

The algorithm now will be:

1. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the tree from the BFS algorithm on the graph (starting from node 1, for uniqueness)
2. For every edge $e=(i,j)$ in the graph, that is not in $\mathcal{T}$ already, w.l.o.g assume $i\le j$, and add a new node with value $j$ to $\mathcal{T}$, and a connection between it and the (original) node $i$ in the tree.

Note that in the new tree, there will be a lot of nodes that have the same number.

To reconstruct the original graph, we will do the following:

1. Create a node for every unique number in $\mathcal{T}$.
2. Add an edge $(i,j)$ if there is a node with number $i$ that has an edge to some node with value $j$

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I am doing, except that I add a global sink to the graph, if and only if it does not already exhibit. Hence, I circument choosing a node of the graph to be the root, but instead use the added global sink. Therefore, regardless of labeling the graph ( e.g., assigning numbers to vertices ) the resulting tree will be identical in construction. I further observed, as you mentioned, an explosion in vertices. Where I really want to get to is that for two constructed trees, their isomorphism would mean that the corresponding input graphs would also have to be isomorphic

Comment: Then great! this should work for any undirected graph (including non-simple ones)

Comment: Im pretty sure this preserves isomorphism (of node **numbers** ), but dont take my word for that

Comment: Yes, it would work for any graph. Thanks for your clarification. What interests me is the property of graph isomorphism for the two graphs, which can then be shown efficiently. I must miss something in my thought process. If T_G is an unambiguous tree representation of G, then showing that T_G isomorph T_H would also show G isomorph H. I recond that either the algorithm to construct T_G is then in exp. time or the T_G is enlarged in size exp., meaning that showing isomorphism for the two graphs would be exp. overall.

Comment: the graph isomorphism problem (GISO for short) is not known to be solvable in polynomial time (but also is not known to be NP-Complete)

if thats what you are trying to solve, then it makes sense this would take exp time overall...

Comment: But it does seem weird, this algorithm doesnt look very exponential to me :o

Comment: I am uncertain about the complexity. But the number of vertices just explodes. I applied my algorithm to this simple graph, https://images.app.goo.gl/pjk4zmrpwaC6Mrgi7   comprising five nodes, yielding a tree that comprises 110 nodes. Interestingly though, I would argue that it is impossible to reconstruct from that tree any other graph than the original input graph. Moreover, such trees can not be "forged", in a way that relabeling a constructed tree is not possible without violated its semantics. And yes, my interest is in the graph isomorphism problem indeed.

Comment: hmmm. the algorithm i have written should have not outputted more than 13 nodes...
I suppose the algorithm you used also somehow encoded the node "values" within the graph with more nodes?